# Android - Can't get the OnTouchEvent to fire in Activity - using MonoDroid (Need the MotionEvent from OnTouch)

Tags: android, touch-event, xamarin.android, gesturedetector

Would anyone by chance have a working example of using GestureListner with Monodroid?  I can't seem to successfully translate what's out on the Net using Java.

I think I am close...  And I think if I can get this "OnTouchEvent" to fire, I could in turn get my GestureDetector Class' OnTouchEvent to fire, and then I would be able to get the swipe motion (or OnFling).

What do I need to do to get this event to fire in my Activity class?  No

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
      m_gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);

      return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
}
```

And I think I definitely need the OnTouch event instead of OnClick because I need the MotionEvent.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Android docs for [OnTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29):

> Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views
>   under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen
>   outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.

Are you sure you aren't handling it in a view? My guess is you probably *should* handle it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to call the override the OnTouchEvent on the Activity. I think that's where you got it wrong. Here's an example on how I did it. Hope it helps.

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    private TextView displayText;
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;
    private GestureListener gestureListener;

    protected override void OnCreate( Bundle bundle )
    {
        base.OnCreate( bundle );

        SetContentView( Resource.layout.main );

        displayText = FindViewById<TextView>( Resource.id.textView );

        gestureListener = new GestureListener( displayText );
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector( this, gestureListener );
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent( MotionEvent e )
    {
        return gestureScanner.OnTouchEvent( e );
    }
}

public class GestureListener : GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
{
    private readonly TextView view;
    private static int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    public GestureListener( TextView view )
    {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool OnDown( MotionEvent e )
    {
        view.Text = "- DOWN -";
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnFling( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( Math.Abs( e1.GetY() - e2.GetY() ) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH )
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if ( e1.GetX() - e2.GetX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.Abs( velocityX ) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY )
                Toast.MakeText( view.Context, "Left Swipe", ToastLength.Short ).Show();
            else if ( e2.GetX() - e1.GetX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.Abs( velocityX ) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY )
                Toast.MakeText( view.Context, "Right Swipe", ToastLength.Short ).Show();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void OnLongPress( MotionEvent e )
    {
        view.Text = "- LONG PRESS -";
    }

    public bool OnScroll( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY )
    {
        view.Text = "- FLING -";
        return true;
    }

    public void OnShowPress( MotionEvent e )
    {
        view.Text = "- SHOW PRESS -";
    }

    public bool OnSingleTapUp( MotionEvent e )
    {
        view.Text = "- SINGLE TAP UP -";
        return true;
    }
}
```